# ¿Qué Template Engine esta reconociendo el IDE Visual Studio cuando uso dos llaves "{{variable}}" en cshtml y como hago para que funcione?

Tags: javascript, c#, cshtml

¿Que Template Engine esta reconociendo el IDE Visual Studio cuando uso dos llaves "{{}}" en cshtml para que pueda usar algun Template Engine en JavaScript adecuado para que funcione?

Este es mi fragmento de codigo:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <div class="callout bg-light-blue-active color-palette">
        <h4>{{NombreCompleto}}</h4>
        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
            <dt>Puesto</dt>
            <dd>{{Puesto}}</dd>
            <dt>Carnet Identidad</dt>
            <dd>{{CarnetIdentidad}}</dd>
            <dt>Area</dt>
            <dd>{{Area}}</dd>
            <dt>Cargo</dt>
            <dd>{{Cargo}}</dd>
        </dl>
    </div>
</div>
```

Por alguna razon el IDE Visual Studio lo reconoce y lo marca con un color distinto al resto (en mi caso esta en rosado), a partir de ello que Template Engine en JavaScript me seria adecuado usar para esas llaves y por fin funcionen

Comment: Podría ser handlebars, pero no es el único que usa esa sintaxis.

Comment: @PabloLozano por que habrian incluido esa sintaxis no?, de todos modos gracias por la respuesta lo checkare ahora mismo